# Injective type family for natural numbers

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write some functions to operate on fixed-size vectors (using the `vector-sized` package). These use `GHC.TypeNats` to encode the length in the type itself. However I'm running into some problems when I want to repeat an operation (`getAllVectors` in this case) a certain amount of times. Since the 2nd argument of `getAllVectors` affects the result type, it seems I need to go through something like what's described [in this page](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/type-nats/matching-on-nats). But this doesn't compile - Haskell complains `FromNat1` is not injective even though I'm pretty sure it is.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import GHC.TypeNats 
import Data.Vector.Sized (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Sized as Vec 

data Nat1 = Zero | Succ Nat1

type family FromNat1 (n :: Nat1) = (c :: Nat) | c -> n 
type instance FromNat1 Zero     = 0
type instance FromNat1 (Succ n) = 1 + FromNat1 n

getAllVectors :: forall s n. [s] -> Nat1 -> [Vector (FromNat1 n) s]
getAllVectors s Zero = [Vec.empty]
getAllVectors s (Succ x) = Vec.cons <$> s <*> getAllVectors s x
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm not strictly tied to using `vector-sized` if there's a better option

Comment: How does it help to pass a `Nat1` to `getAllVectors`? Also, `getAllVectors` is confusing. Could you try to explain what it's supposed to do?

Comment: GHC.TypeNats has a kind `Nat` which is defined as `data Nat` with no constructors (using `DataKinds`). So in order to get actual values represented as peano numbers we have to create our own concrete type.  `getAllVectors s n` returns every possible vector of size `n` with elements in `s`

Comment: What connects the `Nat1` argument to the variable `n`?

Comment: That's the part I wasn't really sure how to do. I came up with a "workaround" using singleton instances (`SNat`) but I couldn't figure out how to make this work with `vector-sized`, so right now I'm just using a regular datatype

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to start with "real" things, and then translate them to the "fakes". Here's how you'd do it for real:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data SNat n where
  SZ :: SNat 'Z
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat ('S n)

data Vec n a where
  Nil :: Vec 'Z a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a

getAllVectors :: forall s n. [s] -> SNat n -> [Vec n s]
getAllVectors s SZ = [Nil]
getAllVectors s (SS x) = Cons <$> s <*> getAllVectors s x
```

Using a singleton ties the size of the natural number argument to that of the vectors in the result.

To make this sort of thing work with the fake types, you're likely to want type families going both ways. Don't be afraid of constraints that look like

```
(ToTL n ~ n', FromTL n' ~ n)
```

if those turn out to make sense.

Notice something else: the implementation using `Data.Vector.Sized` will be pretty inefficient, since consing vectors is slow. Do you really need that?